# The data that comes as HTML echos right on modal window but does not show in PDF

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, mpdf

I am working on codeigniter. I am sending data from a view to a file which takes the data and when I echo it, it shows right on modal window  but  as soon as I  write `$mpdf->Output();` the data does not show up and a screen appears as:
[image: The error output on modal window]

My html being sent is:

```
    $html='';

    $html .='
                <table width="100%" class="pat-demo" id="pqrs_csv_list">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th  class="cols">Measure ID</th>
                            <th  class="cols">Measure Name</th>
                            <th  class="cols">Met</th>
                            <th  class="cols">Not eligible</th>
                            <th  class="cols">Not met</th>
                            <th  class="cols">Exclusion</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';

    foreach ($arr as $aRow)
    {
        if($counter==2) { $bgcolor =""; $counter=1;} else { $bgcolor = "#FFF9F9"; $counter++; }



        $html .='<tr bgcolor="'.$bgcolor.'">
                        <td  class="cols" width="8%">'.$aRow['measureId'].'</td>
                        <td  class="cols" width="55%%">'.$aRow['measureName'].'</td>
                        <td  class="cols" width="8%">'.$this->percentage($aRow[1], $total_visits)."%".'</td>
                        <td  class="cols" width="8%">'.$this->percentage($aRow[2], $total_visits)."%".'</td>
                        <td  class="cols" width="8%">'.$this->percentage($aRow[3], $total_visits)."%".'</td>
                        <td  class="cols" width="8%">'.$this->percentage($aRow[4], $total_visits)."%".'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }

$html .='</tbody>
            </table>';
```

Then the file which takes this HTML and where I try to display it in pdf viewer has the code:

```
    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L', 0, '', 10, 10, 32, 25, 5, 2,2,'P');       
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">'.$header.'</div>');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

$mpdf->defaultheaderfontsize=10;
$mpdf->defaultheaderfontstyle='B';
$mpdf->defaultheaderline=0;
$mpdf->defaultfooterfontsize=10;
$mpdf->defaultfooterfontstyle='BI';
$mpdf->defaultfooterline=0;
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('admin_includes/css/print_pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
//echo $html;/// here it echos right but not goes to pdf
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional headers might need adding. Maybe try a combination of any the following:

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-disposition: attachment');
```

Answer (score 0):

use ob_end_clean(); after header('Content-type: application/pdf');